# Ubuntu 13.10 & HP ENVY m6-1310sa, bad wifi connection

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, hp

I installed Kubuntu 13.10, with the 3.11.0-14 kernel, to a HP ENVY m6-1310sa laptop. My wireless connection was unreliable; it  frequently disconnected and could reconnect only after reloading its driver in the kernel:

```
modprobe -r rt2800pci
modprobe rt2800pci
```

The wireless hardware was a Ralink RT3290:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

Updating my kernel to 3.12, a known fix for this wireless card, introduced a different problem; the display driver failed. I saw a command line at boot.

```
 xwindow
```

resulted in a "no monitor" error.

Comment: fixed by downgrading the kernel, so unlikely to be helpful now

Comment: Yes, this is now not so useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, and it may not be the best one, was to downgrade the kernel to 3.6.11-030611-generic, in the usual manner. i.e. `wget` the debian packages for [v3.6.11-raring](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.6.11-raring/), install the kernel

```
  dpkg -i linux-*
  kate /etc/default/grub
```

Change the default kernel, by replacing

```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

with

```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=0"gnulinux-advanced-604e2e7d-b9e2-4497-bd8b-eb7e9121095e>gnulinux-3.6.11-030611-generic-advanced-604e2e7d-b9e2-4497-bd8b-eb7e9121095e"
```

Updating grub,

```
 update-grub
```

and finally rebooting.